# How to crop part of the image between specified lines in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working on implementation in python the algorithm presented in https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03270. In the following paper there is a part when we create epipolar lines and we want to take part of the image between those lines. Creation of the lines is fairly easy and it can be done with approach presented for instance here https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html. I tried to find a solution that would get me a part of the image between those lines (with some set width) but I couldn't find any. I know that I could manually take values from pixels via calculating if they are under/above lines but maybe there is a more elegant solution to this problem? Do you guys have any idea or maybe experienced similar problem in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

# lets say this is our image
np.random.seed(42)
img =  np.random.randint(0, high=256, size=(400,400), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('random image', img)


# we can create a mask with epipolar points and AND with the original image
mask = np.zeros([400, 400],dtype=np.uint8)
pts = np.array([[20,20],[100,350],[165,240],[30,30]], np.int32)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [pts], 255)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)


filt_img = img&mask
cv2.imshow('filtered image', filt_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this approach! One more question, maybe you know if there is any way to applied resultant mask on two different images and transform it in a way that it would be possible to calculate HOG similarity between them?